# Laravel sail: why could database connection take 5 seconds?

Tags: laravel, database, postgresql, laravel-sail

When using a local database (running in docker, through Laraval Sail), database queries in my Laravel/React application are always done in a fraction of a second. Yet when connecting to a postgresql db on digitalocean, the first query on a page often takes ~5 seconds.

When connecting to the remote database through a database explorer (dbeaver) everything is really fast, both connecting and doing queries are always done in milliseconds.

What could cause this, and how would I go about debugging this? It seems something is being done that always fails, and after a 5 second timeout the Laravel application decides to take a different approach.

[image: screenshot of laravel debugbar showing slow database query]

Comment: You're talking about the same session query in dbeaver right?

Comment: Could you please check if this might be the solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/323356/postgres-connection-establishment-slow

Comment: That solved it!!! Thanks a bunch, I'm connecting with ip-address to the database now, and everything is <1 second

Comment: Good to hear that helped

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of completeness if somebody misses the comment:

There is a known issue in Postgress when using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`. So use `127.0.0.1` to fix your issue. More details can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/323356/postgres-connection-establishment-slow).

Comment: for sake of completeness, use `localhost` for what?